# XML validation in XMLReader()

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xmlreader

I've been trying to work out how to validate XML against XSD in PHP but failed to do so due to lack of examples. I've read about **is_Valid()** etc.

I've came up with example below but it doesn't work properly.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('items.xml');
$reader->setSchema('items.xsd');

//Now how do validate against XSD and print errors here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i created a Performance-Benchmark: XMLReader vs DOMDocument

XMLReader.php:

```
    $script_starttime = microtime(true);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $xml = new XMLReader; 
    $xml->open($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
    $xml->setSchema($xmlschema);        

    while (@$xml->read()) {};

    if (count(libxml_get_errors ())==0) {
        echo 'good';            
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }

    echo '<br><br>Time: ',(microtime(true) - $script_starttime)*1000," ms, Memory: ".memory_get_usage()." bytes";
```

DOMDocument.php:

```
    $script_starttime = microtime(true);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $xml = new DOMDocument(); 
    $xmlfile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $xml->load($xmlfile); 

    if ($xml->schemaValidate($xmlschema)) {
        echo 'good';        
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }

    echo '<br><br>Time: ',(microtime(true) - $script_starttime)*1000," ms, Memory: ".memory_get_usage()." bytes";
```

My Example: 18 MB xml with 258.230 lines

Result:

XMLReader - 656.14199638367 ms, 379064 bytes

DOMDocument - 483.04295539856 ms, 369280 bytes

So i decided to go with DOMDocument, but just try it with your own xml and xsd and use your faster choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created similar answer  regarding validation here:
[Getting PHP's XMLReader to not throw php errors in invalid documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927565/getting-phps-xmlreader-to-not-throw-php-errors-in-invalid-documents/17118613#17118613)

But most important thing is that you cannot validate using XMLReader without passing whole document. The situation is similar to database resultset - you have to iterate (read method of XMLReader) through document nodes and each node is validated only when you read it (sometimes even later)

Comment: I used `set_error_handler('validation_error_handler', E_WARNING);` and handled errors manually which worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). It is much more powerful and mixes a reader and a writer in one - which I see no reason not to. It also has a much more logical interface (IMHO).

Once you do this, [`DOMDocument::schemaValidate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) does what you are after.

Comment: I cannot use DOM because my XML files are massive which DOM cannot handle.

Comment: @DaveRandom  The DOM is powerful, but that power comes with a cost. Both tools have completely different use cases and are powerful in their own way. The dom is very expensive compared to XMLReader. DOM will load the entire document in memory. XMLReader enables you to read a document much more efficiently, plus you can load single nodes into the dom when you need to. You will be able to get better performance and save (potentionally alot of) resources.  This is also true for applications that process smaller XML files.  The "right" choice depends on the requirements. Neither one is "better".